# What are the packages pypy include by default

Tags: python, package, pypy

Does pypy include the entire CPython standard library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batteries-included part of PyPy is the same as CPython. The arrangement may be slightly different since some things like `_ssl` are implemented via cffi, and `datetime` is pure python, but the normal user will not notice the difference, barring bugs. For more information, see https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#extension-modules, which may need updating for python3. Note this includes `ensurepip` which installs pip and setuptools.